# Undefined variable Issue with laravel blade

Tags: php, laravel

In my laravel application, I'm having a list of regions in my DB

This is my controller method

```
public function index()
{
        $region_options = Region::get();

        return view('home',compact('region_options'));
 }
```

and I have following in my blade,

```
@if(!$region_options->isEmpty())
    <ol class="region-pop">
          @foreach ($region_options as $key => $region)
                  <li>{{ $region->name }}</li>
          @endforeach
    </ol>
@endif
```

But when I run this it gave me an error saying, `Undefined variable: region_options`

I'm struggling to find what the issue is...

Comment: Hard to say. With what you provided, it should work. My guess is that you are returning the wrong view or this is the wrong controller method. Are you 100% sure it's ok? Can you triple check it?

Comment: please provide screenshot of error if possible

Comment: @toyi  it also suggesting  that, Possible typo $region_options

Did you mean $regions?

Comment: Fixed the issue by changing $region_options to $regions as laravel suggested, but don't know the reason...